# get the number after zeroes

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I need to get 88090000 after zeroes. How can I do that using awk?

There can be any number of zeroes before the number. But, I need the number after the zeroes.

```
0000000088090000
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add 0.

```
$ awk '{ print $0 + 0 }' <<< '0000000088090000'
88090000
```

Comment: And I always used `echo 'xxx' | cmd` for that... You always learn something new on SO

Answer (score 4):

Using regular expressions:

```sh
echo '0000000088090000' | awk '{ sub(/^0+/, ""); print }'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
echo "0000000088090000" | awk '{ printf "%d\n", $0 }'
```

Comment: I guess I can use gensub.
          bash-2.05b$ echo 0000000088090000 | awk '{ no= gensub(/(^0+)(.+)/,"\\2", "g"); print no; }'
88090000

Answer (score 1):

**Using sed:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo "0000000088090000" | sed 's/^0\+//g'
88090000
```